# Adding a row to database if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a databaste, *visitorsCounter*, and I want to add a new row everytime someone visits the page. I'm getting their IP, and then I check if there isn't a row in the databaste with their IP. If there isn't, I add a new row.

```
$visitor_ip = getUserIP();
if(!isset($db)) $db = connect_db(); // connecting to the databaste with PDO
$userName = $_SESSION['username'];

$query = "SELECT entries from visitorsCounter WHERE ip=:ip";
$stmt = $db->prepare ( $query );
$stmt->bindParam ( ":ip", $visitor_ip);
$stmt->execute ();
$result = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

if($result != null){ // **** if there isn't a row with that IP ****
$addEntryQuery = "UPDATE visitorsCounter SET entries = entries + 1 WHERE ip=:ip";
$stmt = $db->prepare ( $addEntryQuery );
$stmt->bindParam ( ":ip", $visitor_ip);
$stmt->execute ();
}
```

EDIT: adding a row with user code:

```
    $userName = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "INSERT INTO visitorsCounter(ip, entries, user)
    VALUES (:ip, 1,:user)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entries = entries + 1;
        ";
$stmt = $db->prepare ( $query );
$stmt->bindParam ( ":ip", $visitor_ip);
$stmt->bindParam ( ":user", $userName);
$stmt->execute ();


if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$addEntryQuery = "UPDATE visitorsCounter SET user = :user WHERE ip=:ip";
$stmt = $db->prepare ( $addEntryQuery );
$stmt->bindParam ( ":ip", $visitor_ip);
$stmt->bindParam ( ":user", $userName);
$stmt->execute ();
}
```

A visitor come in the website, and the user is null in the database. But when he logins, it stays null. Any idea why?

Comment: I think the first sql statement ( select ) is more or less redundant especially if you were to use `insert into visitorsCounter .... on duplicate key update...` after having set ip as a unique key. That said, more than one user can have the same ip address and a user can have more than one ip ...

Comment: Your logic to check if a row exist doesn't work. `null` != "empty" or "non-existant" if your column has a default of NULL and accepts a NULL value. You could also add an additional where clause.

Comment: @RamRaider You are correct. How can I handle it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- How can I check if I don't get anything in return?

Comment: Example: `if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){...}` or `COUNT(col)` with HAVING and COUNT, and adding another entry to the `WHERE` clause as an option. Quite a few ways to do this actually.

Comment: You have been given answers below; see those Dave.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing this as one statement.  The key idea is `on duplicate key update`.

So, add a unique index to your table so the *database* enforces one row per ip:

```
create unique index unq_visitorscounter_ip on visitorsCounter(ip);
```

Then, update/insert the value as:

```
INSERT INTO visitorsCounter(ip, entries)
    VALUES (ip, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entries = entries + 1;
```

In addition to simplifying your code, this is the more correct way of expressing the logic.  You code can have race conditions if the same `ip` is being inserted at the same time by different applications/threads.

Comment: I think you are missing the `UPDATE` to the `ON DUPLICATE KEY`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's good. But I want to add a user to the row. I added some code, I edited the main question. Can you please check that out? Thanks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff A visitor come in the website, and the user is null in the database. But when he logins, it stays null. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you never get inside the "update" if-statement is that you shouldn't check for `null`, but instead check for a `false` value.
According to the documentation for [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) you will get `false` returned on failure.

So your code should work better with a

```
if($result !=== false) {
    ...
}
```